# deployment of the bot in microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework

is there possible to deploy our bot in visual studio our project bot in azure resources is there possible to deploy??
also with database and mail sending SMTP server
we have subscription and all
then how to deploy bot in azure

Comment: Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy you bot to Azure. Its a MVC WebApi project like others. If you need SMTP mail, you can use services like SendMail to that. For Databases, you can also use one of the many that azure provides (eg. DocumentDB, SqlAzure).